# Entity - Loop infinito em conversão JSON

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, api

### O que acontece

Estou tendo um problema ao utilizar o Entity com minha aplicação `MVC`. O que acontece é que ao converter uma classe pra JSON o programa entra em um loop infinito e acaba retornando `no-content`

### Exemplo

Tomando como exemplo o relacionamento (1-n):

Um `Autor` tem vários `Posts`.

O que eu percebi fazendo debug é que com uma Conversão de `JSON` vai ocorrer a seguinte interpretação:

*Um autor tem vários posts. Um post tem um autor. Um autor tem vários posts. Um post tem um autor...*

Claro que não é bem essa a minha situação de classes, mas o que ocorre é a mesma ideia. Quando vou ver na minha API a resposta é `no-content`. Quando eu insiro `[JsonIgnore]` nas minhas propriedades isso é ajustado, mas aí perco um dos lados da relação, o que é um preço que não posso pagar para o funcionamento da aplicação.

Gostaria de saber como proceder e fazer o `Entity` não entrar nesse loop infinito.

### EDIÇÃO: Código

#### Models

**Team.cs**

```
public class Team : TEntity
{
  public int ID {get; set;}

  public string Function {get; set;}

  public int LeaderID {get; set;}

  public User Leader {get; set;}

  public List<TeamUser> Users {get; set;}
}
```

**TeamUser.cs**

```
public class TeamUser : TEntity
{
  public int ID {get; set;}

  public int TeamID { get; set; }

  public int UserID { get; set; }

  //Aqui, sem essa anotação já retornaria "no-content" (acredito eu, devido ao bug do loop)
  [JsonIgnore]
  public virtual Team Team { get; set; }

  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User : TEntity
{
  public int ID {get; set;}

  ...

  // o mesmo aqui
  [JsonIgnore]
  public virtual IList<TeamUser> Teams {get; set;}

  // e aqui
  [JsonIgnore]
  public virtual IList<Team> TeamsLeadered {get; set;}
```

#### Arquivos Configuration do Entity

**TeamConfiguration.cs**

```
...
builder
  .Property(t => t.LeaderID)
  .HasColumnName("ID_LIDER");

builder
  .HasOne(t => t.Leader)
  .WithMany(u => u.LeaderedTeams)
  .HasForeignKey(t => t.LeaderID);
```

**TeamUserConfiguration.cs**

```
builder
  .Property(tu => tu.TeamID)
  .HasColumnName("ID_EQUIPE");

builder
  .Property(tu => tu.UserID)
  .HasColumnName("ID_USUARIO");

builder
  .HasOne(tu => tu.Team)
  .WithMany(t => t.Users)
  .HasForeignKey(tu => tu.TeamID);

builder
  .HasOne(tu => tu.User)
  .WithMany(u => u.Teams)
  .HasForeignKey(tu => tu.UserID);
```

**GetAll()**

```
public IEnumerable<Team> GetAll()
{

    var teams = _context.Teams
       .Include(t => t.Leader)
       .Include(t => t.Users)
       //Aqui eu precisaria de um ThenInclude(t => t.User) mas retorna no-content
       .ToList();

    return teams;
 }
```

Comment: Poste o código que você está usando para tal rotina amigo

Comment: Adicione seu código para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: Pergunta editada, com o código adicionado. Ali eu explico que, da forma que está, funciona, mas pra fazer uma busca dos usuarios de um Team por exemplo, já não consigo.

Comment: Como você está convertendo seu objeto em JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Quando for realizar a serialização do seu objeto adicione a propriedade `JsonSerializerSettings` e configure para ignorar os loops quando for realizar a serialização.

Se você estiver usando o `Newtonsoft.Json` para realizar a serialização ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objeto1, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

Caso esteja utilizando ASP.NET Core Web Api, no seu WebApiConfig.cs adicione essa configuração:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Referência do ASP.NET Core: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7